# Does RDS instance reboot on changing Multi AZ option?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, cloud, rds

does the RDS instance reboot if we change the single AZ to multi AZ or vice versa ?

Answer (score 0):

Turning enabling or disabling multi-AZ does not require a restart of the database engine, therefore, no downtime.

However, I believe taking a snapshot of the current RDS and launching a new RDS with Multi-AZ is the best practice.